# Python insert via psycopg2 into postgresql failing

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm a noob so having trouble with inserting into Postgresql via psycopg2. I have a file with lines such as:

```
42::Dead Presidents (1995)::Action|Crime|Drama
43::Restoration::Drama
```

I'm trying to change those lines into insert statements via the following code:

```
import psycopg2

try:
   db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='password'")
   cur = db.cursor()
except:
   print("Unable to connect to the database.")

for line in open('./movies.dat'):
   (movie_id, movie_name, tags) = line.split('::')[0:3]
   ypos = movie_name.rfind('(')
   ypos2 = movie_name.rfind(')')
   if ypos < 0:
      cur.execute("insert into movies values (%s, %s, %s, null)", (movie_id, movie_name, tags))
   else:
      cur.execute("insert into movies values (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (movie_id, movie_name[0:ypos].strip(), tags, movie_name[ypos+1:ypos2].strip()))
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I have no idea why, or how to go about debugging the general error of psycopg2. Anybody have any helpful ideas?

This is python 3.2.3 and postgresql 9.2

Comment: Check the Postgres' log. What you see is the last error and you need the first one - the one causing the failure of the whole transaction.

Comment: 2012-09-15 22:48:42 CAT STATEMENT:  insert into movies values ('29', 'City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995', 'Adventure|Drama|Fantasy|Mystery|Sci-Fi', '')

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with that log, except for the fact that my year extractions is not working correctly and it might need a semicolon at the end. Do you reckon it's the semicolon?

Comment: If I just call it with hardcoded values it gives the same error, even if I use a semicolon

Comment: 2012-09-16 07:48:10 CAT ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2012-09-16 07:48:10 CAT STATEMENT:  insert into movies values (1, 'Dogma', 'Action', 2010)
2012-09-16 07:48:23 CAT ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2012-09-16 07:48:23 CAT STATEMENT:  insert into movies values (1, 'Dogma', 'Action', 2010);
2012-09-16 07:49:06 CAT ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: We need to find the first error, all other (`ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`) are consequence of the first one. And please add the extra info to your question and don't put it as comments.

Comment: There are no errors other than that in the log

Comment: Can you include the schema of the movies table?

Answer (score 1):

```
except:
    print("Unable to connect to the database.")
```

You're ignoring a fatal error. You should:

1. Print a more useful error message (containing the actual error)
2. Stop execution (either remove this catch statement and let the exception propagate up, or return an error code).

Comment: That part is only there for the database connection bit and does not relate to my problem.